# PHP Sticky Forms

Tags: php, html, forms, sticky

I've been doing a project for php, about sticky keys. It's quite straight forward. However I'm getting a few errors... I'm using CodeLobster.

Can anyone help me find my error on this ?
I've been looking for 2hrs now, I tried the debug, but I don't really know how to use it here.

Thank you so much. Any helps will be appreciated

This is what I am getting:
[image]

Output should be this:
[image]

```
<html><head><title>Empty Fields</title>
<body><div align="center">
    <h2>Validating Input</h2>
    <?php
        $errors = array();

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            validate_input();

            if(count($errors) != 0){
                display_form();
            }
            else{
                echo "<b>OK! Go ahead and Process the form!</b><br/>";
            }

        }
        else{
            display_form();
        }

        function validate_input(){
            global $errors;

            if($_POST['name'] == ""){
                $errors['name'] = "<font color='red'>***Your name?***</font>";
            }

            if($_POST['phone'] == ""){
                $errors['phone'] = "<font color='red'>***Your phone?</font>";
            }
        }

        function display_form(){
            global $errors;
    ?>
            <b>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                What is your name?<br/>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" /><br/>
                <?php echo $errors['name']; ?><br/>
                What is your phone number?<br/>
                <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>" /><br/>
                <?php echo $errors['phone']; ?><br/>
                <input type="reset" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" /><br/>
            </form></b>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you show some image of error?

Comment: you need to add isset condition, or empty condition whichever you want to use, the thing is that, the page shows notices those are not errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Can you please check once this code:-

<html><head><title>Empty Fields</title>
<body><div align="center">
    <h2>Validating Input</h2>
    <?php
        $errors = array();

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            validate_input();

            if(count($errors) != 0){
                display_form();
            }
            else{
                echo "<b>OK! Go ahead and Process the form!</b><br/>";
            }

        }
        else{
            display_form();
        }

        function validate_input(){
            global $errors;

            if($_POST['name'] == ""){
                $errors['name'] = "Your name?";
            }

            if($_POST['phone'] == ""){
                $errors['phone'] = "Your phone?";
            }
        }

        function display_form(){
            global $errors;
    ?>
            <b>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                What is your name?<br/>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){echo $_POST['name'];} ?>" /><br/>
                <?php if(isset($errors['name'])){echo $errors['name'];} ?><br/>
                What is your phone number?<br/>
                <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){$_POST['phone'];} ?>" /><br/>
                <?php if(isset($errors['phone'])){echo $errors['phone'];} ?><br/>
                <input type="reset" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" /><br/>
            </form></b>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to revise your code, There are many point to fixed.
First, you need to keep $_POST['name'] and $_POST['phone'] in variable for easy to use in each function.
Like this,

```
$name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '');
$phone = (isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '');
```

You also need to add code below to first line in function that need to use this variable

```
global $name;
global $phone;
```

In function display_form you need to check $errors['name'] and $errors['name'] is empty or not before print(echo) the line.

```
if (isset($errors['name'])) echo $errors['name'];
if (isset($errors['phone'])) echo $errors['phone'];
```

So, Finally the code should be like the below, I tried this code without error.

```
<html>
<head><title>Empty Fields</title>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h2>Validating Input</h2>
    <?php
        $errors = array();

        $name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '');
        $phone = (isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '');

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            validate_input();

            if(count($errors) != 0)
            {
                display_form();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<b>OK! Go ahead and Process the form!</b><br/>";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            display_form();
        }

        function validate_input(){
            global $errors;
            global $name;
            global $phone;

            if($name == '')
            {
                $errors['name'] = "<font color='red'>***Your name?***</font>";
            }

            if($phone == '')
            {
                $errors['phone'] = "<font color='red'>***Your phone?</font>";
            }
        }

        function display_form(){
            global $errors;
            global $name;
            global $phone;
    ?>
            <b>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                What is your name?<br/>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /><br/>
                <?php if (isset($errors['name'])) echo $errors['name']; ?><br/>
                What is your phone number?<br/>
                <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" /><br/>
                <?php if (isset($errors['phone'])) echo $errors['phone']; ?><br/>
                <input type="reset" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" /><br/>
            </form></b>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use isset($var); to avoid Undefined index: EROOR on php.

echo isset($_POST['name']);
echo isset($_POST['phone']);

wherever you need.